# Wordle Game Additional Delete Button Error

Tags: swift

I am currently developing a wordle game and I'm facing difficulties while attempting to implement a delete button feature. As a beginner in coding, I am seeking assistance to identify and resolve the error in my code. The project consists of multiple files, but I would like to focus on the specific issue within the KeyboardViewController file for now.

At the bottom of the KeyboardViewController file, I encountered an unexpected error message: 'Cannot find type 'View' in scope.' This error message suggests that there is an issue related to the recognition of the View type within the current scope. It is worth noting that the project utilizes SwiftUI for the user interface design.

To provide a more thorough solution, I would appreciate guidance on how to resolve this error. Additionally, if there are any specific code snippets or additional error messages that would be helpful in diagnosing the issue, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Keyboard View Controller File:

```swift
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func keyboardViewController(
        _ vc: KeyboardViewController,
        didTapKey letter: Character
    )
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var previousKey: Character? // Declare the previousKey property
    
    weak var delegate: KeyboardViewControllerDelegate?

    let letters = ["qwertyuiop", "asdfghjkl", "zxcvbnm"]
    private var keys: [[Character]] = []
    

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.register(KeyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: KeyCell.identifier)
        return collectionView
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        for row in letters {
            let chars = Array(row)
            keys.append(chars)
        }
    }
}

extension KeyboardViewController {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return keys.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return keys[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: KeyCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? KeyCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let letter = keys[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: letter)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let margin: CGFloat = 20
        let size: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.size.width-margin)/10

        return CGSize(width: size, height: size*1.5)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        var left: CGFloat = 1
        var right: CGFloat = 1

        let margin: CGFloat = 20
        let size: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.size.width-margin)/10
        let count: CGFloat = CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section))

        let inset: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.size.width - (size * count) - (2 * count))/2

        left = inset
        right = inset

        return UIEdgeInsets(
            top: 2,
            left: left,
            bottom: 2,
            right: right
        )
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let letter = keys[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        
        previousKey = letter // Store the current key as the previous key
        delegate?.keyboardViewController(self, didTapKey: letter)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var previousKey: KeyboardViewController? // Declare the previousKey property

    func button() { // Use lowercase "b" for function name
        previousKey?.removeLetterFromCurrentWord() // Modify this line based on the appropriate function or method
    }

    var label: some View { // Update the label declaration
        Image(systemName: "delete.backward.fill")
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .heavy))
            .frame(width: 40, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .background(Color.unused)
    }
    .disabled(previousKey?.currentWord.count == 0 || !dataModel.inPlay)
    .opacity((previousKey?.currentWord.count == 0 || !dataModel.inPlay) ? 0.4 : 1)
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use some SwiftUI code in your `MyViewController` class. Everything else is UIKit. Replace the SwiftUI code with UIKit code.

Comment: In other words, you should not mix UIKit and SwiftUI like you do.
 Views are struct, and only meaningful in other `Views`, not in classes.

 Note also, that if you want to use some SwiftUI, then you need `import SwiftUI`
 in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that `View` is a SwiftUI type and you aren't importing `SwiftUI`.

Your real problem is that, even if you do import `SwiftUI`, you can't just create `SwiftUI` views and put them in a `UIKit` view controller. The paradigms for using `UIKit` and `SwiftUI` are different. It is possible to mix them but you probably shouldn't attempt to do so whilst you are still "a beginner in coding". Even if you do mix them, the view controller is the wrong place to put a view (in UIKit).

I suggest you choose one or other of the paradigms and stick to it. `SwiftUI` is probably the simpler of the two to get going but does require understanding of some relatively tricky Swift concepts. `UIKit` is a more traditional model (it comes from Objective-C) and probably would be easier for a programmer experienced in some other language.

`SwiftUI` is allegedly "the future" but, to my mind, is still a bit immature and hence some things you think should be easy turn out to be hard - but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Hi JeremyP, I have recently shared an updated version of my code on the post, incorporating all the changes you suggested regarding the use of UIKit. I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a moment to review the code and assist me in identifying any remaining issues that need to be addressed. Your support would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much for your help.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/77406701/22831030